# is virtualbox compatiple whith a windows xp computer

Tags: virtualbox

i am trying to install virtualbox on my windows xp computer but it says that it hasn't passed windows logo testing.
I downloaded it from the vurtualbox website

Comment: this question is for https://superuser.com/ I think

Comment: i found out it is i just had to restart. thx for the answer anyway. :)